# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) : BookNLP

Tags: utf-8, nlp, character-encoding, ascii, text-processing

I am trying to run BookNLP model on a txt file in Colab, but I keep getting an error.

the code:

```
input_file="alice.txt"
output_directory="alice"
book_id="alice"

booknlp.process(input_file, output_directory, book_id)
```

the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-7fd43958471a> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 book_id="alice"
      5 
----> 6 booknlp.process(input_file, output_directory, book_id)

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/encodings/ascii.py in decode(self, input, final)
     24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     25     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 26         return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
     27 
     28 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Looking at other posts about the same error, I know I should set the encoding to UTF-8 but I am a bit unsure how to do that in this particular case.

Comment: Without the code, we are also not sure how to do it. Check to the person who wrote the code.